# Compute $\text{Tor}_i^R(k,\mathfrak{a}^n)$

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $R=k[x,y]$, $\mathfrak{a}=(x,y)$ be an ideal of $R$, how to compute $\text{Tor}_i^R(k,\mathfrak{a}^n)$ for all $i\ge 0$ and $n\ge 1$? Here $\mathfrak{a}^n$ denotes the ideal obtained by taking product of $\mathfrak{a}$ with itself, $n$ times.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Koszul complex gives a free resolution of $k$:
$$0\to R\to R^2\to R\to k\to0$$
where the map $R^2\to R$ is given by $(f,g)\mapsto xf+yg$
and $R\to R^2$ is given by $h\mapsto (y,-x)$. So $\textrm{Tor}_*^R(k,M)$
is the homology of the complex
$$0\to M\to M^2\to M\to0$$
where the maps are $m\mapsto(ym,xm)$ and $(m_1,m_2)\mapsto xm_1+ym_2$.
Now you just have to set $M=\mathfrak a^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found that “$\text{Tor}_0^R(k,\mathfrak{a}^n)=\mathfrak{a}^n/\{xm_1+ym_2|m_1,m_2\in \mathfrak{a}^n\}$, $\text{Tor}_1^R(k,\mathfrak{a}^n)=\{(m_1,m_2)|xm_1+ym_2=0, m_1, m_2\in\mathfrak{a}^n\}$, $\text{Tor}_i^R(k,\mathfrak{a}^n)=0, i\ge 2$. Could you please tell me how to simplify them?

Comment: What you have these is $\text{Tor}_0$ is $a^n/a^{n+1}$. Indeed $\text{Tor}_0(k,M)=k\otimes_RM=M/aM$.

Comment: Also $\text{Tor}_1$ is what you've written but factored out by the image of $M\to M^2$. I think it comes out as zero, but you should check it....

Comment: Yes, I forgot to type the image, sorry. I think in the last line of your answer, $m\mapsto (ym,xm)$ should be $m\mapsto (ym,-xm)$. Right?